# Is it possible to run Firefox bookmark using tasker?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tasker

What I really want is to run (open) a Firefox bookmark from within tasker. That bookmark contains a javascript code and if opened using "browse url", it will not work because it is opened in a new tab. I have a webpage that I want to apply a javascript code on it and the only way to do this is by saving that code in a bookmark and open the bookmark to achieve the task. I want that task to be automated by tasker. Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: why not just run the javascript code as a userscript?

Comment: Tomaski. Can you please make it easy for me with a simple example? Thanks